# HTML 5 WebSocket

Tags: sockets, html

I just read about HTML 5's WebSocket interface. How can I start trying this? What browser versions have implemented this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrV9jJQn_MA it looks like there's a patch that enables it in Mozilla Firefox ( doesn't come native yet ).

```
see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug...

In order to apply the patch, you have to:
1. Download the patch from the link above
2. Download the mozilla source code:
hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ src
3. Apply the patch:
patch -p1 -f /.../downloaded-patch
4. Prepare your .mozconfig, following this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Build_Documentation
5. Build:
make -f client.mk
6. Run it
```